# How to call one xib whenever app load?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have one xib. Like drop down option for selection many language from my table view when user press drop down arrow. So all this stuff I designed and I kept separate file.

Now, the thing is whenever app load I need to show this xib at first to select the language with blur transparent background. And also in my home screen I have one menu option. In that I have many options like home,shop,order,Language,log out.

So now when user press Language that time also I need to show my xib to select the language with transparent xib file.

Now how can I overcome, anybody have any idea in that?

Comment: What exactly you want? Do you want to know how to load xib or anything else??Also always put some code you tried so far so that we can help you better.

Comment: I haven't try any code i just designed the xib file.Now i have one view called "select language view".Now when ever app load i need to show this view as blur back ground to select the language from the drop down list under my "select language view"..So not only on app load and also i need to show that view in my menu option list.That means in my home screen i have one menu button.In that menu i have one option "select language".So that time also i need to show that "Select language view" with blur back ground...Now its clear ??

Comment: Why not use a seperate view controller to deal with the language options?

Comment: Okay.But i don't know how to handle that/Okay if so i have view controller instead of xib.Now what i idea should i use to do that thing as i mentioned above comments

Answer (score 0):

You can load Xib like this:

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("YourXibName", owner: self, options: nil)
```

As per my understanding you want to show same `Xib` multiple times at various places. So I think this can help you.